# Boost asio udp socket sending to different ip address

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, boost-asio

I have one udp server receiving messages from multiple remote clients. When it receives one message, I copy the endpoint and reply to the client at the same IP address on port 5000 where each client is listening.

I have tried multiple debbuging strategies, and printing the endpoint right before I send the reply message gives me the correct IP address and port.

The sender:

```
    std::cout << udp_remote_endpoint.address().to_string();
    std::string str(packet.begin(), packet.end());
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    io_service.post(
        [this, packet]()
        {
            udp_socket.async_send_to(
                boost::asio::buffer(packet),
                udp_remote_endpoint,
                boost::bind(
                    &uds::handle_write,
                    this,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
                )
            );
        }
            );
```

On the receiver, I get the udp_remote_endpoint and before sending, I set the socket endpoint:

```
    new_addr.endpoint = socket.get_udp_remote_endpoint();
    new_addr.endpoint.port(5000);
    socket.set_udp_remote_endpoint(new_addr.endpoint);
```

For example, this output:

```
192.168.1.131K-131-1559147491761155
```

Is actually sending to the IP 192.168.1.130. The message contents are correct "K-131-1559147491761155"

Comment: Some redirections, routing active in your network infrastructure? Also the `0` in the last part of the IP address is usuallly dedicated to a network entry point, the actual server which serves the request, doesn't necessarily have the same IP address.

Comment: You didn't capture the endpoint!

Comment: I was capturing the endpoint. I don't know why they were using io_service.post(), but when I removed it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I removed the `io_service.post` and it worked!

```
`std::cout << udp_remote_endpoint.address().to_string();
std::string str(packet.begin(), packet.end());
std::cout << str << std::endl;
//io_service.post(
//    [this, packet]()
//    {
        udp_socket.async_send_to(
            boost::asio::buffer(packet),
            udp_remote_endpoint,
            boost::bind(
                &uds::handle_write,
                this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
            )
        );
//    }
//);`
```

Comment: There are multiple issues with this code.
1. Need to make sure underlying memory for the buffer (in this case, `packet`) is still valid. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/async_send_to/overload1.html
2. Can't use a single send buffer. If multiple clients connect at the same time,  async_send_to will be called for each client. All the calls will use a single send buffer which is problematic.